# jquery Datepicker: Change position of prev and next buttons

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker

Trying to use datepicker for arabic language. I am able to change all the contents like months and days in arabic so as the datepicker format in RTL.

BUT.
I am not being able to change position of prev and next buttons. Their positions are not changed. Is there anyone out there to help me to do this?

In English:
[image]

In Arabic:
[image]

Please do comment, if question is not clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change right and left style properties on the prev and next buttons  like this:

```
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev:hover {
     left: auto;
     right: 2px;
}

.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next:hover {
    right: auto;
    left: 2px;
}
```

Enter whatever px works for you.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy, because Jquery already has a feature for RTL.
Do following in the initialization of the datepicker

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ isRTL: true });

for more information:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-isRTL

**Follwing is only for above user**

**note:** I think you have to remove what have you done for **"datepicker format in RTL"**

Comment: Using $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ isRTL: true });, this is how i got the calender in right direction format. For your kind information, "next" and "prev" buttons are at same place and i want to interchange their positions / place.

Comment: see the link they are getting changing.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByRHQ5kZfPCHM29JT0JnTmJtQUU/edit